# Ability to set the context of the expression

Tags: dynamic-expresso

Is there a way to set the context of the expression in [Dynamic Expresso library](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso), so that we can do something like the following:

```
interpreter.Eval("FirstName", new Parameter("person", new { FirstName="Homer", LastName="Simpson"}));
```

rather than

```
interpreter.Eval("person.FirstName", new Parameter("person", new { FirstName="Homer", LastName="Simpson"}));
```

Maybe we could have a another option that would say that the first parameter is to be used as the context for the expression.

I guess there could also be another version of Parse and Eval methods that simply takes the expression text and a simple object value that will serve as the expression context.

Other than that and the lack of support for dynamic types, I am really liking this library.  I had worked on something similar, but had not added support for extension methods and generic method calls.

Thanks for the great library,
Neal

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in solution but you can simulate it in many ways:

**Option 1: Inject an expression**

```
var workingContext = new { FirstName = "homer" };

var workingContextExpression = Expression.Constant(workingContext);
var firstNameExpression = Expression.Property(workingContextExpression, "FirstName");

var interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.SetExpression("FirstName", firstNameExpression);

Assert.AreEqual(workingContext.FirstName, interpreter.Eval("FirstName"));
```

Basically I inject an expression using `SetExpression` method. The injected expression is the property that you want to be available.

**Option 2: Use this/me/it variable**

You can inject a variable that will contain your working object. I usually call it `this` (or `me` or `it` depending on the application).

```
var workingContext = new { FirstName = "homer" };

var interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.SetVariable("this", workingContext);

Assert.AreEqual(workingContext.FirstName, interpreter.Eval("this.FirstName"));
```

**Option 3: A combination of the previous solutions**

```
var workingContext = new { FirstName = "homer" };

var interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.SetVariable("this", workingContext);
var firstNameExpression = interpreter.Parse("this.FirstName").LambdaExpression.Body;
interpreter.SetExpression("FirstName", firstNameExpression);

Assert.AreEqual(workingContext.FirstName, interpreter.Eval("FirstName"));
```

Equal to the first solution but I generate the expression using the parser itself.

Consider that all solutions assume that you must have an `Interpreter` instance for each context.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Dynamic Expresso library.

Comment: Hi Davide, thanks for responding so quickly. Yes, I can see how that approach would work for Eval, but it seems that we would not be able to use Parse to build a function in this manner. I would be better if the the variable "this" could be a parameter instead.

Comment: What I really want to do is something like this:
var interpreter = new Interpreter();
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "this");
interpreter.SetExpression("FirstName", Expression.Property(parameter, "FirstName"));
interpreter.SetExpression("LastName", Expression.Property(parameter, "LastName"));
Func<Person, object> func = interpreter.Parse<Func<Person, object>>("FirstName", "this");

But of course, the parameter name argument on the Parse function would need to be the parameter that I created in the beginning.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, one option would be to simply make the following method of the interpreter class protected rather than private:

Expression ParseExpression(string expressionText, Type expressionType, params ParameterExpression[] parameters)

We could then inherit from your interpreter and leverage your great parser for these types of scenarios. Once I had the parsed expression tree, I could compile it using the following line:

Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(expression, parameter).Compile();

Comment: @user3574702 Yes I will think about it. I have just created a new issue on https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso/issues/18

Comment: Thanks Davide! I really like the SetExpression capabilities and this would allow us to inherit from the interpreter and use parameters in these expressions.

Kind Regards,
Neal Borelli

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [DynamicExpresso v2.13.0](https://github.com/dynamicexpresso/DynamicExpresso/releases/tag/v2.13.0), it's possible to define a variable named `"this"`, that will be used for implicit resolution:

```cs
var target = new Interpreter();
target.SetVariable("this", new { FirstName="Homer", LastName="Simpson"});

// 'this' variable is used implicitly
Assert.AreEqual("Homer", target.Eval("FirstName"));

// 'this' variable can also be used explicitly
Assert.AreEqual("Homer", target.Eval("this.FirstName"));
```